# How do I use Dapper to insert a list<myobject> as parameter to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, list, dapper

I have a SQL Server table with 10 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE [bank].[CommonPostingsFromBankFiles]
(
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BankRegistrationNumber] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [BankAccountNumber] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [BankName] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [BankAccount] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [PostingAmount] [DECIMAL](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [PostingDate] [DATE] NOT NULL,
    [Primo] [CHAR](1) NULL,
    [PostingText] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL,
    [HideThisRecord] [BIT] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_CommonPostingsFromBankFiles] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BankRegistrationNumber] ASC,
                               [BankAccountNumber] ASC,
                               [PostingAmount] ASC,
                               [PostingDate] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
)
```

and a stored procedure that takes 7 parameters:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [bank].[spInsertCommonPostings]
    (@BankRegistrationNumber INT,
     @BankAccountNumber BIGINT,
     @BankName NVARCHAR(50),
     @PostingAmount DECIMAL(18, 2),
     @PostingDate DATE,
     @Primo CHAR(1),
     @PostingText NVARCHAR(100))
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM bank.CommonPostingsFromBankFiles
                   WHERE BankRegistrationNumber = @BankRegistrationNumber
                     AND BankAccountNumber = @BankAccountNumber
                     AND BankName = @BankName
                     AND PostingAmount = @PostingAmount
                     AND PostingDate = @PostingDate)
        INSERT INTO bank.CommonPostingsFromBankFiles (BankRegistrationNumber, BankAccountNumber,
                                                      BankName, PostingAmount,
                                                      PostingDate, Primo, PostingText)
        VALUES (@BankRegistrationNumber, @BankAccountNumber,  
                @BankName, @PostingAmount, 
                @PostingDate, @Primo, @PostingText);
END;
```

What I want is to use Dapper to write a `List<Postings>` to the table using the stored procedure.

I have searched and searched but found no example that helped me.

If I do a

```
connection.Execute(sql: "spMyStoredProc", MyList, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

I get an error

> Procedure or function spMyStoredProc has too many arguments specified

If I replace the name of the stored procedure with the SQL from the stored procedure and set `CommandType` to Text it works as expected.

Could anybody please post me an example showing how to insert my list using my stored procedure.

Comment: Your procedure needs to accept a table-valued parameter if you want to pass a list of objects into it. You will need to define a `CREATE TYPE...AS TABLE...` that resembles your `CREATE TABLE` and instruct Dapper to recognize that. This is exemplified here: https://dapper-tutorial.net/parameter-table-valued-parameter

Comment: When you use command-text, Dapper can check which properties are needed, from the SQL. When you call an SP, it can't - it has to assume everything declared is wanted - and in this case, the assumption is incorrect. Or basically: "what @Caius said"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplistically, and assuming the names of the properties in your C# object are identical to the names of the parameters in your stored proc, you could:

```
MyList.ForEach(x => connection.Execute(sql: "spMyStoredProc", x, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure));
```

If the param/props aren't aligned it may be simplest to provide an anonymous type populated with values from x that covers them

```
MyList.ForEach(x => connection.Execute(
  sql: "spMyStoredProc",
  new { BankRegistrationNumber = x.BankRN, ... }, 
  commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
));
```

For a list of 10 objects it will invoke the proc 10 times; it's not the fastest way to do it, but I don't think you've stated any particular goals re performance etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your suggestion solved my problem. My collection contains approx 1.000 elements but I have no problem spending four seconds on that.